# AVR gcc build produces non-working compiler

Tags: gcc, avr, avr-gcc, binutils

I'm trying to build binutils-2.39 and gcc-7.5.0 following the instruction here:

https://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/install_tools.html

These instructions have worked for me in the past.  However with the above versions at least I get a non-working compiler.  It fails like this:

```
$ avr-gcc test.c -o test
/home/tuser/local/avr/lib/gcc/avr/7.5.0/../../../../avr/bin/ld: cannot find -lm: No such file or directory
/home/tuser/local/avr/lib/gcc/avr/7.5.0/../../../../avr/bin/ld: cannot find -lc: No such file or directory
```

I haven't had much luck with google for these errors.  Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like my mistake was expecting the link step of compilation to work before avr-libc was installed.  The above "cannot find" messages apparently refer to components normally provided by avr-libc.

Since the compile and link of a simple test file didn't work, I didn't think building avr-libc would either.  But it did, and after installation
then building of the original (basically empty) test program did also.

This probably should have been obvious but something pathological in my normal (non-test user) setup is causing the ./configure of avr-libc to fail in a way that let me astray.  Sorry if this cost anyone any time.